# Multiple facets of behavior in one scenario?

Tags: bdd, scenarios

I was trying to gain insight into my own problems when I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616499/valid-bdd-scenario-steps-given-when-then-when). To my understanding, two different functionalities are being expressed and tested (look at the two Whens and two Givens about them). Is it right to do so?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of writing scenarios (and for that matter class-level examples too).

One is to use a single example per scenario.

Another is to have *one aspect of behavior* per scenario.

In this scenario, the behavior in the cases of both inactive and active users provide something valuable. Without one or the other, the behavior is meaningless. So putting them in one scenario makes sense. This also provides a pragmatic benefit in that it often takes time to initialise the context for a scenario.

A good reason to split them might be if a third behavior comes into play (for instance, you have suspended users as well as active and inactive ones).

If you have *separate* aspects of behavior, it's usually valuable to illustrate them with different examples. For instance:

```
Given Fred bought a fridge for $100
When Fred returns the fridge
Then he should be refunded $100
And the fridge should be returned to stock.
```

The two outcomes are quite clearly two different aspects of behavior and involve different stakeholders - the customer and the shop owner - so it would make more sense to split them up.

```
Given Fred bought a fridge for $100
When Fred returns the fridge
Then he should be refunded $100

Given Fred bought a fridge for $100
When Fred returns the fridge
Then the fridge should be returned to stock.
```

However, be pragmatic about it. If it's more readable or comprehensible one way than the other, then that should take priority over any hard-and-fast rules. I will say that it took me a while to learn how to do this effectively, so mostly it comes with experience.